# Delay differential equation when the delay tends to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

Consider a delay differential equation with initial condition:
$$ x_\tau'(t)=f(t,x_\tau(t),x_\tau(t-\tau)),\,t>0;\quad x_\tau(t)=g(t),\,t\in [-\tau,0], $$
where $\tau>0$ is the delay. My question is under which conditions $x_\tau$ tends to $x$ as $\tau\rightarrow0$, where $x(t)$ solves the problem for $\tau=0$:
$$ x'(t)=f(t,x(t),x(t)),\,t>0;\quad x(0)=g(0). $$
Is this a standard result in the literature? I thought of using Gronwall's inequality under a Lipschitz condition for $f$: $|f(t,x_1,y_1)-f(t,x_2,y_2)|\leq K(|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|)$. Then we derive the inequality $|x_\tau(t)-x(t)|\leq K\int_0^t |x_\tau(s)-x(s)|ds+K\int_0^t |x_\tau(s-\tau)-x(s)|ds$, but I do not know how to work with the second integral $\int_0^t |x_\tau(s-\tau)-x(s)|ds$.

Comment: Just raising a question, here: do you need Libschitz in the second argument? Since you're wanting to consider what happens when $\tau\to 0,$ I wonder if you only need Lipschitz in the third argument.

Comment: Under uniqueness assumptions (e.g. local Lipschitz continuity) you can expect uniform convergence on closed and bounded intervals, but nothing better. This should follow from general results for continuous dependence of solutions of delay differential equations on their right hand side. But don't expect uniform convergence on the entire domain of existence of the solution with $\tau = 0$.

Comment: @HansEngler Is there a formula for the size of the interval (or bounds for a sub interval) one can expect convergence on?

Answer (score 1):

To work with the integral inequality that you derived,
$$
|x_\tau(t)-x(t)|\leq K\int_0^t |x_\tau(s)-x(s)|ds+K\int_0^t |x_\tau(s-\tau)-x(s)|ds
$$
you can proceed as follows:

First show a uniform in $\tau$ bound for $\|x_\tau(s)\|$ on some interval $[0,T]$. *Clearly this has to be possible if the convergence result that you want to prove is true.*

This implies a uniform bound for $\dot{x_\tau}(s)$, say $\|\dot{x_\tau}(s)\| \le C_0$ for all $\tau$ and all $s \in [0,T]$.

Assuming also $\|\dot{g}(s)\| \le C_0$ for $s \le 0$ (which is natural), it then follows that   $\|x_\tau(s-\tau) - x_\tau(s)\| \le \tau C_0$ for all such $\tau$ and $s \le T$ and therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
|x_\tau(t)-x(t)|& \leq K\int_0^t |x_\tau(s)-x(s)|ds+K\int_0^t |x_\tau(s-\tau)-x(s)|ds \\
& \leq 2 K\int_0^t |x_\tau(s)-x(s)|ds + KtC_0 \tau 
\end{aligned}
$$
Apply Gronwall's inequality and uniform convergence of $x_\tau$ to $x$  follows on $[0,T]$.